# Not possible to knit a markdown file

Tags: r, knitr

I want to knit my r markedown file but I am getting this error:

```
... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```

I read some posts an installed this package:

```
install.packages("stringi")
```

When I try to install it I got this message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/X1/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/stringi_1.1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 14289948 bytes (13.6 MB)
downloaded 13.6 MB

package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘stringi’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\X1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO4JAo9\downloaded_packages
```

After that I did

```
library(stringi)
```

and load the package.

But when I try to knit the markedown now I get the same message:

```
... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```

Any idea? Thank you.

PS: I am using windows 10.

**Update**

Solution: Reinstalled RStudio. Then I got this error:

```
    Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'backports'
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I found the solution for this problem in that thread:

[backports 1.1.1 package fails to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416458/backports-1-1-1-package-fails-to-install)

```
require(devtools)
install_version("backports", version = "1.1.0")
```

Comment: Have you tried `remove.packages("stringi")` or `detach("package:stringi", unload=TRUE)` or both before installation?

Comment: For  `detach("package:stringi", unload=TRUE)` I got `Error in detach("package:stringi", unload = TRUE) : invalid name argument` and for `remove.packages("stringi")` there are the same problenms as before. But I got this additional message when I deinstall the package `Removing package from ‘C:/Users/X1/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)`

Comment: `detach()` just unloads the package if its loaded. `"as ‘lib’ is unspecified"`is normal and ok assuming your package is installed in the default directory.

Comment: Perhaps you want consider to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570912/error-in-installation-a-r-package