# Error when installing rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this error when trying to run install.packages("rmarkdown"). Can someone please let me know what's wrong?

> - installing *source* package 'rmarkdown' ...
>     ** package 'rmarkdown' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :    there is no
>     package called 'backports' ERROR: lazy loading failed for package
>     'rmarkdown'
> - removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/rmarkdown'
> - restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/rmarkdown' Warning in install.packages :   running command
>     '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program
>     Files\R\R-3.2.3\library"
>     C:\Users\knguyen\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0KyOP9/downloaded_packages/rmarkdown_1.6.tar.gz'
>     had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>     ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘C:\Users\knguyen\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0KyOP9\downloaded_packages’
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: The error is telling you that `backports` is missing. Considering that doesn't appear in the *depends* list for `rmarkdown` it makes me wonder what version you are using. Can you post your session info?

Answer (score 0):

Try install the package backports  as mentioned in the error.

Comment: Why downvote this answer? I assume it would resolve the issue. Also compare this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417290/7667096

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the new R Version https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.4.3/.
I tried installing R markdown in my R studio, but it keeps looping to ask me to install the package. The R version on my R studio was version 1.1, and after I installed the new R Version, installing the R Markdown package was a success. Hopefully this could help.